# c++ overload functions match

Tags: c++, c++14

I felt confused for c++ overloaded functions mathing.
see code below:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
  void func();
  void func(int);
};

void Base::func() { cout << "Base::func()" << endl; }

void Base::func(int a) { cout << "Base::func(int)" << endl; }

class Derived : public Base {

public:
  void func(const string &);
  void func(const string &&);
  void func(bool);
};

void Derived::func(const string &s) {
  cout << "Derived::func(string &)" << endl;
}

void Derived::func(const string &&s) {
  cout << "Derived::func(string &&)" << endl;
}

void Derived::func(bool b) { cout << "Derived::func(bool)" << endl; }

int main() {

  Derived d;
  d.func("biancheng");
  d.func(false);

  // d.func(1);
  // d.Base::func(1);

  cout << endl << "completed .." << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

and the results:

```
Derived::func(bool)
Derived::func(bool)

completed ..
```

For calling `d.func("biancheng");`, the result printed matched the func(bool) function definition.  Can somebody help me understand what is the cause?

I thought it would be one of the func(const string &s) or func(const string &&s).

Comment: I wondered why I never stumbled upon this in real code, and I think overloading functions with `std::string` and `bool` parameters really is a bad idea also for other reasons. I think it's fair to say that you should only overload functions if you as the caller _don't care which overload is chosen_.

Comment: Try: `string str = "biancheng";` followed by `d.func(str);`

Answer (score 3):

`"biancheng"` is of type `char const[10]`. It decays to `char const*`. From here there are two possible conversions. There is the implicit (built in) conversion to `bool` and the implicit conversion to the class type `std::basic_string<char, /*char-traits-type and allocator*/>`. Conversions to class types are always considered *after* built in conversions, so the pointer to `bool` conversion is chosen here by the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

In your code, when you called function `d.func("biancheng");`, it matched with `d.func(bool b)` because the string parameter "biancheng" can be implicitly converted to TRUE [boolean parameter]. Therefore, `d.func(bool b)` was called instead of `d.func(const string &s)`   ||  `d.func(const string &&s)`.

Comment: Why to `false`? It will be converted to pointer `const char*` and then to `bool` true value, because string literal is never a `nullptr`.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention, you are correct.